# In the book Frankenstein, Volume 3, Chapter 3, there is a sentence that I don't understand will you help me?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*I do not understand the stuff in bold.*
Victor say's, "**All was again silent; But his words wrung in my ears. Why had I Not followed him, and closed with him and closed with him in mortal strife? I shuddered to think who might be the next victim sacrificed to his insatiate revenge.**

Comment: It would help to explain what exactly you find difficult about the text, and show what research you’ve done.

Comment: Are you sure it's not “his words *rang* in my ears”?

Answer (score 1):

> All was again silent;

This is fairly self-explanatory.

> But his words wrung in my ears.

I was still thinking about what he said.

> Why had I Not followed him

Also self-explanatory.

> and closed with him in mortal strife?

Why had I not attacked and killed him?

> I shuddered to think who might be the next victim sacrificed to his insatiate revenge.

I am fearful that he will kill someone else because he is very violent and dangerous, and that I will be partly to blame because I missed the opportunity to kill him.